# ¿ Dónde guardar un documento PDF dentro de mi App?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando guardar un documento PDF en mi App pero no sé dónde ponerlo y cómo formular el sencillo `intent` para abrirlo.

Yo tenía puesto esto :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
```

Pero no se me abre ningún PDF.

Editado:

Tengo ahora esto:

```
Intent intentpak = new Intent();
                        intentpak.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intentpak.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                        intentpak.setData(Uri.parse("www.yyyy.com/zzz.pdf"));
                        startActivity(intentpak);
```

Pero se me abre el pdf y cada vez se me guarda en el móvil y me va ocupando espacio cada documento que me bajo, quiero guardarlo dentro y no llenar mi memoria.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que normalmente hago es descargarme los archivos en un directorio dentro del paquete de la aplicación y comprobar si ya existe el archivo antes de descargarlo, si ya existe le doy la opción de abrirlo o descargarlo de nuevo.

Para guardar en la carpeta que te he mencionado utilizo lo siguiente:

```
File f = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
f.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ nombre_archivo;
```

Después para comprobar si existe en la carpeta utilizo lo siguiente:

```
File archivoDescargadoAnt = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
ext = new File(archivoDescargadoAnt.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+nombre_archivo);

if(ext.exists())
      existeArchivo = true;
```

Y por último:

```
if(existeArchivo ){
      archivoGuardado = ext.getAbsolutePath();

      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
           dialog.setMessage("El archivo ya existe.¿que desea hacer?");
           dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
           dialog.setCancelable(true);
           dialog.setPositiveButton("Abrir"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Abrir
                        abrirArchivo(getActivity(), archivoGuardado);
                        dialog.cancel();
                  }
           });
           dialog.setNegativeButton("Descargar de nuevo"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Volver a descargar
                        descargarArchivo(recurso);
                        dialog.cancel();
                  }
           });

           dialog.show();
 }
 else
     descargarArchivo(recurso);
```

Y para abrir el archivo utilizo lo siguiente:

```
public void abrirArchivo(Context context, String archivo){
      try {
          Uri uri  = Uri.fromFile(new File(archivo));
          Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

          //obtenemos la extension del archivo y su mime type para abrirlo
          String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
          String mimetype = "";

          if(extension != null && extension.length()>0)
               mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.toLowerCase());
          else{
               //mimetype = "*/*";
               mimetype = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(archivo);

          }

    //    Log.i(tag, "uri: " + uri.toString() + "extension: "+ extension + " mimetype: " + mimetype);

          intentUrl.setDataAndType(uri, mimetype);
    //             intentUrl.setData(uri);
          intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intentUrl);
      }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
          Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.no_app_instalada), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }catch (Exception e){
          Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.error_abriendo_archivo), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
}
```

Comment: si te ha servido mi respuesta te agradecería que la marcaras como correcta para que les pueda servir a otros usuarios de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: para los que o tenemos ni idea....
no as dicho dentro de que zona hay que ponerlo: me refiero a ponerlo en oncreate, o en public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { o donde¿?

Comment: @noexistent pues dependerá un poco de lo que haga tu código, en este caso creo que el usuario se descargaba el documento, pero no indicaba cómo por lo que podría ir dentro de un AsyncTask o un Service. Por otro lado si lo que quieres es sólo abrir el archivo puedes poner la lógica dentro del OnClick del button